# Pass OffsetTop value into the Javascript Scroll() Method Dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, scroll, offset

I have a scroll function on my site where if someone clicks a menu item it scrolls down to a particular div. To achieve this I obtained the offsetTop property value in my console, and then manually inputted it into the scroll method.

**Current situation**

```
var menuItem = document.getElementById("menuitem");
var box = document.getElementById("box");

// the following line line returns 730px
console.log(box.offsetTop)

menuItem.addEventListener("click", function() {
    scroll(0, 730px;)
});
```

**Desired Situation**

How do i get it so that i can pass the offsetTop value into the scroll method dynamically, instead of working it out manually and then adding it in?

I can't seem to work out how to do this?

Any help really appreciated,

Comment: Why not just pass `box.offsetTop` directly to the `scroll` method?

Comment: why not scroll(0, box.offsetTop+'px')

Comment: I tried those two ideas initially and they didn't work